# How to accurately identify an AMD GPU?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, gpu, amd-radeon

I own a laptop with AMD Radeon graphics and the main problem is that I can't discover its real name.
When looking in device manager or anywhere else I see "AMD Radeon HD 6000/7000 series", which I discovered is the name of the driver, not the GPU itself.

Can anyone tell how can I get the exact name of my gpu of my laptop?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.  The product page for your laptop should indicate what GPU that is installed.

Comment: @Ramhound - reading between the lines, I've tweaked the question & dropped in a generic answer. Feel free to edit further.

Comment: run `dxdiag` and go to the "Display 1" tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to https://www.amd.com/en/support & download their auto-detect driver scanner.

Best info is always right from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an utility like [CPU-Z](https://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) or similar to obtain the *PCI device ID*.
Once you got the PCI device ID of your graphics card (see also below), go to [The PCI ID Repository](https://pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PC?sort=name?restrict=). The data consists of two 32-bit hex values like

> 1002:731F --- Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5700 / 5700 XT]

for the latest [AMD Radeon™ RX 5700 XT Graphics](https://www.amd.com/en/products/graphics/amd-radeon-rx-5700-xt).

This method does work for all PCI devices:

- Acquire the PCI device ID xxxx:yyyy (see also below)
- Look it up on *the PCI ID Repository*

---

You can also retrieve that information from the Windows *Device Manager* or *WMI* as well. To access that data with WMI, use

```
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET description
```

to get your graphics card name, and

```
wmic PATH Win32_videocontroller GET pnpdeviceid
```

to get a string that also contains the PCI device ID, that can be used in the above procedure. To get the *VENDOR_ID* use the 4 hex digits after the `VEN_` part of the string. And to get the *DEVICE_ID*, use the 4 hex digits after the `DEV_` part of the string. Both, together, form the unique 64-bit identification that can be queried in the above mentioned database.